# Force dotnet nuget to load library from runtimes-folder

Tags: .net, f#, nuget, cross-platform

I am trying to build a Nuget package out of an F# project using dotnet.
The project uses (a small subset of) SDL2.

I want to include SDL2 as a native shared library, i.e. .so on linux, .dylib on mac and .dll on windows.

My P/Invoke wrappers all use the `DLLImport` attribute similar to below:

```
[<DllImport(libName, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
extern int SDL_Init(uint32 flags)
```

My (heavily shortened) `.fsproj` file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
     ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="lib/*.so" >
      <PackagePath>runtimes/linux-x64/native/%(Filename)%(Extension)</PackagePath>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Pack>true</Pack>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I build the project with `dotnet build`, create the NuGet package with `dotnet pack` and can subsequently reference and use it with `#r "nuget:MyPackage"` in f#-scripts.
This works and I am happy about that.
However, if I use my package on a linux system that already has `libSDL2.so` installed, e.g. in `/usr/lib`, the system-library is loaded and used instead of the library included in the NuGet package.
(At least this is what `LD_DEBUG=libs dotnet fsi someScript.fsx` tells me).

Is there a way to reorder the paths used for searching for libraries, s.t. the included library is used by default?